# Why am I getting weird runtime in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, runtime

I have a project to sort array[500000] using quickSort algorithm,
I've implemented quickSort like this:

```
public void sort (int[] array){
        sort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }

private void sort (int[] array, int start, int end){
        if (start >= end) {
            return;
        }

        var boundary = partition(array, start, end);
        sort(array, start, boundary - 1);
        sort(array, boundary + 1, end);
    }

    private int partition(int[] array, int start, int end){
        var pivot = array[end];
        var boundary = start - 1;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            if (array[i] <= pivot)
                swap(array, i, ++boundary);

        return boundary;
    }

    private void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2){
        var temp = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = temp;
    }
```

So I check it;
First, I create array with **500000** elements, using some other class (No need to post), and then I get a copy of the array to be able to use it as unsorted again.
When I pass the first array to the first object and calculate the runtime, I get something around 300ms, but when I sort the second array (Copy of first unsorted array), I get something around 150000ms.
The question is; why these 2 objects which are made from one class, sort the same array in a very different time?
Note that I used both *System.currentTimeMillies();* and *System.nanoTime();*, No difference.
Also ran it on both linux and Window, no difference again.

Edited:
Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        var arrayBuilder = new ArrayBuilder();
        var firstArray = arrayBuilder.getArray();
        var secondArray = arrayBuilder.getArray();
        
        var quickSort1 = new QuickSort();
        long firstSortStart = System.nanoTime();
        quickSort1.sort(firstArray);
        long firstSortEnd = System.nanoTime();
        long firstSortTotal = firstSortEnd - firstSortStart;
        System.out.format("Original QuickSort (Version 1) took %d nano seconds. \n", firstSortTotal);
        
        var quickSort2 = new QuickSort();
        long secondSortStart = System.nanoTime();
        quickSort2.sort(secondArray);
        long secondSortEnd = System.nanoTime();
        long secondSortTotal = secondSortEnd - secondSortStart;
        System.out.format("Changed QuickSort (Version 2) took %d nano seconds. \n", secondSortTotal);
//      this takes ~183861470 nano seconds
        quickSorter2.sort(copiedArray);
//      this takes ~218316931575 nano secondes
```

Comment: Benchmark.NET? That isn't a thing in java world, perhaps @Fildor thought this was a C# question. The proper tool for benchmarking is [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the array? Running quick sort on an already sorted array can be very slow.

Comment: It's better to post code than to describe it. What is the "first object"? What does it do? Does it sort the array? By what method? If you post a [mcve] instead, we'd be able to see for ourselves if you are really copying the array, if the other object does something more clever than you think etc.

Comment: It would be cleaner to set `startTime` and calculate the timespan only in `sort(int[] array)`. Currently if you reuse an instance of your sorter class it will use the start time of when the instance was created (because that is when `startTime` is set) and not when sorting started. So every subsequent sorting done by that instance will appear to take longer than the previous one.

Comment: @OrangeDog ; Yes, I copied. You can see in main class I posted.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ; Everything is really clear. First object sorts first array, second one sorts second array (which is exactly the same as firsst array - unsorted)

Comment: @Marcono1234; I also did that, but I get the exact same time. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Not just about the time, my laptop fan starts working when second sorting starts doing its job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not copy the array:

```java
var copiedArray = array;
```

What it does is declare another variable pointing to **the same** array.
Running quicksort on an already sorted array [is usually very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63686324/476716).

To actually [copy an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5785745/476716), you need to do e.g.:

```java
var copiedArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
```

Any remaining time differences will likely be due to JIT optimisations. Use a benchmarking system like [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) to account for them.

Edit:
Now you've changed it to two different random arrays, so the runtime difference is now due to the elements being different.