# Why the quickest sort algorithm is always merge sort among merge,insertion,quick sort and heap sort when I am writing a c++ function to test?

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

[Book page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gah0J.jpg)

[Book page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRq0R.png)

The 4th question is my homework. I am asked to write 4 sort functions to compare the worst time they use. The length is n.
My code is as follows

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void Swap(int &a,int &b)
{
    int temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
void partition(int *a, int left, int right){
    int mid = (left+right)/2;                   
    int t1 = a[left], t2 = a[mid], t3 = a[right];
    if((t1 <= t2 && t2 <= t3) || (t3 <= t2 && t2 <= t1))
    {Swap(a[right], a[mid]);}               
    else if((t2 <= t1 && t1 <= t3) || (t3 <= t1 && t1 <=t2))
    {Swap(a[right], a[left]);}   
}
void QuickSort(int* a,int left,int right)
{
    if(left<right)
    {
        int i;
        i=left;
        int j;
        j=right+1;
        partition(a,left,right);
            int mid = (left+right)/2;                   
    int t1 = a[left], t2 = a[mid], t3 = a[right];
    if((t1 <= t2 && t2 <= t3) || (t3 <= t2 && t2 <= t1))
    {Swap(a[right], a[mid]);}               
    else if((t2 <= t1 && t1 <= t3) || (t3 <= t1 && t1 <=t2))
    {Swap(a[right], a[left]);}   
        int pivot=a[left];
        do{
            do i++;while(a[i]<pivot);
            do j--;while(a[j]>pivot);
            if(i<j) Swap(a[i],a[j]);
        }while(i<j);
        Swap(a[left],a[j]);
        QuickSort(a,left,j-1);
        QuickSort(a,j+1,right);
    }
}
void InsertSort(int* arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j-1]) {
                Swap(arr[j], arr[j - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
void Merge(int *initList,int* mergedList,int l,int m,int n)
{
    int i1=l,iResult=l,i2=m+1;
    for(;i1<=m&&i2<=n;iResult++)
    {
        if(initList[i1]<=initList[i2])
        {
            mergedList[iResult]=initList[i1];
            i1++;
        }
        else
        {
            mergedList[iResult]=initList[i2];
            i2++;
        }
    }
        for(int temp=iResult;i1<m+1;i1++,temp++)
        {
            mergedList[temp]=initList[i1];
        }
        for(int temp=iResult;i2<n+1;i2++,temp++)
        {
            mergedList[temp]=initList[i2];
        }
}

void MergePass(int *initList,int *resultList,int n,int s)
{
    int i=1;
    for(;i<=n-2*s+1;i+=2*s)
    {
        Merge(initList,resultList,i,i+s-1,i+2*s-1);
    }
    if((i+s-1)<n)Merge(initList,resultList,i,i+s-1,n);
    else
        for(int temp=i;temp<n+1;temp++)
        {
            resultList[temp]=initList[temp];
        }
}
void MergeSort(int* a,int n)
{
    int *tempList=new int[n+1];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i*=2)
    {
        MergePass(a,tempList,n,i);
        i*=2;
        MergePass(tempList,a,n,i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        a[i]=tempList[i];
    }
    delete[]tempList;
}
void adjustHeap(int* arr, int i, int length) {
    int temp = arr[i];//先取出当前元素i
    for (int k = i * 2 + 1; k <=length; k = k * 2 + 1) {
        if (k + 1 <=length && arr[k] < arr[k + 1]) {
            k++;
        }
        if (arr[k] > temp) {
            arr[i] = arr[k];
            i = k;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    arr[i] = temp;
}

void adjust_heap(int* a, int father, int len)
{
    int left = 2 * father;
    int right = 2 * father + 1;
    int max = father;
    if( left <= len && a[left] > a[max])
        max = left;
    if( right <= len && a[right] > a[max])
        max = right;
    if(max != father)
    {
        Swap( a[max], a[father]);
        adjust_heap(a, max, len);
    }
}
 
void HeapSort(int* a, int len)
{
    for(int i = len / 2; i >= 1; --i) 
        adjust_heap(a, i, len);
 
    for(int i = len; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        Swap(a[1], a[i]);     
        adjust_heap(a, 1, i - 1); 
    }
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        a[i]=a[i+1];

}
void heapAdjust(int*nums, int idx,int len){
        int temp=nums[idx];
        for(int j=idx*2+1;j<len;j=j*2+1){           
            if(j+1<len&&nums[j]<nums[j+1])  {j++;}  
            if(temp>nums[j])  {break;}        
            nums[idx]=nums[j];              
            idx =j;                           
        }
        
        nums[idx]=temp; 

    }
  void heapSort(int* nums, int n,int k){
        for(int i=n/2-1;i>=0;i--)   
        {
            heapAdjust(nums, i,n);
        }
        for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            if(k)   {k--;}
            else {break;}             
            swap(nums[0],nums[i]);
            heapAdjust(nums,0,i);     
        }
    }
void MaxMerge(int arr[],int l,int r)//transform the array so it is the most complex for merge sorting
{
if(r-l>1)
{
    int *temp=new int[r-l+3];
    temp[0]=0;
    for(int i=0,j=1;i<=r-l;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0){
            temp[j+(r-l+1)/2]=arr[i+l];
        }
        else{
            temp[j]=arr[i+l];
            j++;
        }
    }  
    for(int i=l,j=1;i<=r;)
    {
        arr[i]=temp[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    delete[]temp;
    MaxMerge(arr,l+(r-l)/2,r);
    MaxMerge(arr,l,l+(r-l)/2-1);
}
else
{
    int t=arr[l];
    arr[l]=arr[r];
    arr[r]=t;
}

}
void Permute(int *a,int n)
{
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i=n;i>=2;i--)
    {
        int j=rand()%i+1;
        swap(a[j],a[i]);
    }
}
 void TimeTest(int n)
 {
     if(n!=0){
        int *QuickSortTest=new int[n+1];
        int *InsertSortTest=new int[n+1];
        int *HeapSortTest=new int[n+1];
        int *MergeSortTest=new int[n+1];
        for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++)
        {
            QuickSortTest[j]=j;
            InsertSortTest[j]=n-j;
            MergeSortTest[j]=j;
            HeapSortTest[j]=j;
        }
        MaxMerge(MergeSortTest,1,n);
        Permute(HeapSortTest,n);
        clock_t begin1=clock();
        for(int j=0;j<500;j++)
        {
            QuickSort(QuickSortTest,1,n);
        }
        clock_t end1=clock();
        clock_t begin2=clock();
        for(int j=0;j<500;j++)
        {
            heapSort(HeapSortTest,n,n-1);
        }
        clock_t end2=clock();
        clock_t begin3=clock();
        for(int j=0;j<500;j++)
        {
            InsertSort(QuickSortTest,n);
        }
        clock_t end3=clock();
        clock_t begin4=clock();
        for(int j=0;j<500;j++)
        {
            MergeSort(QuickSortTest,n);
        }
        clock_t end4=clock();
        cout<<"n="<<n<<" QuickSort: "<<end1-begin1<<endl;
        cout<<"n="<<n<<" HeapSort: "<<end2-begin2<<endl;
        cout<<"n="<<n<<" InsertSort: "<<end3-begin3<<endl;
        cout<<"n="<<n<<" MergeSort: "<<end4-begin4<<endl;
        delete[]QuickSortTest;
        delete[]InsertSortTest;
        delete[]HeapSortTest;
        delete[]MergeSortTest;
     }
 }
int main()
{
    //int num1[]={500,1000,2000,4000,3000};
    for(int i=0;i<=4000;i+=100)
    {TimeTest(i);cout<<endl;}

}
```

I have already test for every function, and they are all right.
However,the result is that
[image: Results]

I am confused that why merge sorting is always the quickest?

Comment: Quicksort has very bad worst case performance. Is your quicksort implementation correct? Are you generating the lists with random values each time? Test it against some other known quicksort implementation and see how it does.

Comment: Have you enabled compiler optimisations? Please post all relevant parts of your question as text not images

Comment: If you need code review of your implementation of algorithms and tests then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is meant for that. If you need ideas how to benchmark sorting algorithms then Boost.Sort https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/sort/doc/html/index.html is giving good example. I am confused is not good question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quicksort to already sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686324/quicksort-to-already-sorted-array)

Comment: 499 of your 500 iterations work on sorted arrays. Also, your arrays are meaninglessly tiny.

Answer (score 1):

Both your algorithms and tests need some tender loving care.

For example I replace your `InsertSort` with less naive version of it

```
void InsertSort(int* arr, int n)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key)
        {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

After that `InsertSort` suddenly starts to wash floors with others in your tests. That is so because the test arrays are already sorted in most of the runs and it is rather good with such.

Among your original algorithms `MergeSort` was best with sorted input and so it won.

Comment: Even a no-swap-early-exit bubblesort crushes the other tests precisely because it best-cases to O(n) on already sorted data. I concur, both the algorithms and the tests need some TLC.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok I edit TLC into answer. :D